# Black bars on transparency in gif when displaying in Java?

Tags: java, graphics, photoshop, gif, animated-gif

For a project for our Advanced Java class, a group of friends and I are building a fighting game. To display the characters, we're saving animated gifs to ImageIcons and then in the paintComponent method of the panel we're using

```
icon.paintIcon(this.getAssociatedGamePanel(), g, getLeftSide(), getTopY());
```

to display the icon, as this was the easiest way I could find to display the icon. The only problem is some of that the gifs will display strange black bars in parts of the transparencies. For Example,
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAjZY.gif

is our gif for the low kick. When we display it in Java, it looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6HBb.png

I've tried using various gif optimization tools, making sure I erased the transparency completely, and various other things, but haven't been able to make the bars disappear. One image optimization tool turned the bars white, but that's the only thing I've been able to do. What are some things I could try in order to get rid of the black bars?

Comment: I'm just guessing as I don't have the time to go through too much atm, but I'd say the size of your gif and your canvas you are drawing to are different. Just to test for testing sake, I would recommend stretching the gif to the size of the canvas. If it works, simply backtrack and fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

@wewtaco, I noticed that your PNG file has wider dimension than the Gif file and I am guess that could be a reason the black bars are showing up. Can you try keeping the size same or the view area of the icons same...and see if that fixes...Also, the PNG file is not background transparent...it might be carrying some colors from its original source..that could be another reason.